# JSON "value" into HTML

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am trying to access the Water Discharge value in a USGS.gov JSON output.

[USGS JSON URL](http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=01199000&parameterCd=00060)

I want to pull to the number value from:

```
"values":[{"value":[{"value":"2510"
```

and place it into a div or span to be styled with CSS.

*(the value is live and will continue to drop from my post as 2510)*

I am totally new to JSON and The USGS file is so convoluted I can't make heads or tails of it.I was hoping to keep it SUPER simple like this FLICKER API example I found at [API.JQUERY.COM](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

I imagine it will start someting like

```
  <span id="usgs_span"></span>

<script>
var usgs = "USGS JSON URL;
  $.getJSON( usgs, {
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $.values.value( "<span>" ).appendTo( "#usgs_span" );
    });
})();
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6zz7F/)

```
(function() {
  var APIURL = "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=01199000&parameterCd=00060";
  $.getJSON( APIURL, {   })
    .done(function( data ) {


         $.each( data.value.timeSeries[0].values[0].value, function( i, item ) {
              $( "#test" ).html($( "#test" ).html()+":"+item.value);
         });

    });
})();
```

Whenever you stuck to find what value to parse you can use http://www.jsontree.com/ to get a tree view on clicking required node it will show you what is the parser object.

Comment: I also ended up using the same code to access and convert water temperature data for another usgs data point.

 `<div id="nmTEMP"></div>
 
<script>
 
(function() {
  var APIURL = "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=01200600&parameterCd=00010";
  $.getJSON( APIURL, {   })
    .done(function( data ) {


         $.each( data.value.timeSeries[0].values[0].value, function( i, item ) {
              $( "#nmTEMP" ).html((($( "#nmTEMP" ).html()+item.value) * 1.8 + 32).toFixed(0));
         });

    });
})();
 
</script>`

Comment: Hello, so its like access to http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=01200600&parameterCd=00010 has been blocked. I can still load the data in my browser but the function can no longer access it. (403 error) Any way around this?

Comment: try using https they have forbidden http access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the data is horribly convoluted, but you can still dig through the response like you would with any other. Pull the data and convert it to an object first, and log it to the console.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://waterservices.usgs.gov"
        + "/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=01199000&parameterCd=00060";

xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    console.log(data);
};
```

Expand properties of the data logged to the console until you find what you're looking for.

Then look at the properties you've expanded and use them to resolve your value.

```
var myValue = data.value.timeSeries[0].values[0].value[0].value;

// do something with myValue
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3QUxX/

---

It looks like this data is better suited to XML than JSON. They probably wrote this service with XML in mind and provided JSON as a concession. You may have an easier time omitting the `format=json` URL parameter and extracting the data you need from the XML response instead.

Comment: oh wow converting it to xml does make it much more clear. Startlingly clear…